# How do I always return values where a field is False, but toggle if the values show when the field is True in Power BI? (Worded better in Body)

Tags: powerbi

Basically,

I have a Power BI query import from SQL. One of the columns, called `IsLocked`, contains a boolean value.
In my Power BI Table, I always want the `IsLocked = False` records to be showing.

I also want an input for the user to determine whether to show `IsLocked = True` as well.

I can easily have a user filter to show `IsLocked = False` or `IsLocked = True`, but how do i get a filter to show `IsLocked = False` or `IsLocked = True or IsLocked = False`

Ideally, I would have something with the same functionality as a tick box to Show/Hide `IsLocked = True`

I hope that made sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

at your slicer, select formatting, go to selection controls and deselect Multi-select with CTRL. You ll have the tickboxes that way:

[image]

Comment: I've already got this, but it's not quite what I was looking for, I always need option 1 active, then have a toggle to show option 2 as well as option 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is a filter with the option to select multiple values. You can use the following steps:

1. Create a slicer for "Islocked"
2. Under the format section of slicer, select selection controls
3. Turn off "Multi-Select with CTRL"

This should give what you are looking for.

Edit:

You can do whatever you are looking for using bookmarks. The following link walks you through how you can create a bookmark and use it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks

Comment: I've already got this, but it's not quite what I was looking for, I always need option 1 active, then have a toggle to show option 2 as well as option 1

Comment: In that case you will have to use bookmarks...I have added an edit to the answer which gives the basics....

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you